# How to release an application in production mode using pycharm?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pycharm, release

I try to make an appliction using python and tkinter. At the moment I have couple of .py files where I intregated those .py files in my main UI python file or module.

I want to release this application in production mode using pycharm. What is the best way to do that? Is there any facility to create a Windows installable app?

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a Windows installer/executable of your Python app?

Comment: PyCharm won't help you with this task. If you need a single executable to distribute try PyInstaller or similar libraries.

Comment: @SubhashBhushan.....yes..

Comment: @pavel ...is there any help document